# Calculating Humidity, Wet Bulb Temp and Dew Point

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling, applications

I have been trying to simulate a climate system, but I have hit a wall. I am trying to calculate Humidity. But to calculate Humidity you need the Wet Bulb Temperature, but to calculate the Wet Bulb Temperature you need humidity. I also want the Dew point temperature but to calculate that you need humidity again.

In my system I have access to `Temperature`, `Elevation` and `Latitude`. Am I missing a step? How can I calculate these values?

Do I need to create a pressure system using the temperature data? but then how can I use the pressure data to calculate the previous values?

I have searched and searched but can not find an answer to the problem. Every site I go to expects a variable that I don't have.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your information is not sufficient because none of the data reflects how much water is in the air.  You can have the same values of Temperature, Elevation and Latitude with very dry or very wet air.  You need to model sources and sinks of water in the air, like evaporation, rain, wind blowing in air from somewhere else, etc.